# Sending emails using Django: No errors thrown when given wrong email id and password

Tags: python, django, email

I was trying to send emails through Django. It does not throw any errors when given a wrong password and email id.

```
#settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sgshds@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'hshsa'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

I made a function in views.py

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings
def sendit(request):
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [from_email]
    msg = EmailMessage('hello', 'body', from_email, to_email)
    msg.send()
    return HttpResponse('dasasad')
```

The output on terminal:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: hello
From: sgshds@gmail.com
To: sgshds@gmail.com
Date: Sat, 31 Dec 2016 08:35:19 -0000
Message-ID: <20161231083519.12551.52266@vatsal-Inspiron-3543>
body
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[31/Dec/2016 08:35:19] "GET /sent/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7
```

P.S.  I also have problems in receiving emails. I think, authentication requests are made from smtp to log in to the account and make it send an e-mail. If anybody could help with that.

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: @ruddra  I am using django version 1.9

Comment: @ruddra I have found the solution though. In my file I somewhere had 'EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
so everything got printed in the Terminal. Removing that made everything working.